# PHP GD: How to get imagedata as binary string?

Tags: php, zip, gd

I'm using a solution for assembling image files to a zip and streaming it to browser/Flex application. (ZipStream by Paul Duncan, http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/).

Just loading the image files and compressing them works fine. Here's the core for compressing a file:

```
// Reading the file and converting to string data
$stringdata = file_get_contents($imagefile);

// Compressing the string data
$zdata = gzdeflate($stringdata );
```

My problem is that I want to process the image using GD before compressing it. Therefore I need a solution for converting the image data (imagecreatefrompng) to string data format:

```
// Reading the file as GD image data
$imagedata = imagecreatefrompng($imagefile);
// Do some GD processing: Adding watermarks etc. No problem here...

// HOW TO DO THIS??? 
// convert the $imagedata to $stringdata - PROBLEM!

// Compressing the string data
$zdata = gzdeflate($stringdata );
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One way is to tell GD to output the image, then use PHP buffering to capture it to a string:

```
$imagedata = imagecreatefrompng($imagefile);
ob_start();
imagepng($imagedata);
$stringdata = ob_get_contents(); // read from buffer
ob_end_clean(); // delete buffer
$zdata = gzdeflate($stringdata);
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason it fails with nested `ob_start`. I found M.i.X's answer below to be a better solution.

Answer (score 22):

```
// ob_clean(); // optional
ob_start();
imagepng($imagedata);
$image = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: ob_get_clean() essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean(), so this solution is slightly more elegant that the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 21):

The php://memory stream can be used when output-buffer juggling is unwanted.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

```
$imagedata = imagecreatefrompng($imagefile);

// processing

$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
imagepng($imagedata,$stream);
rewind($stream);
$stringdata = stream_get_contents($stream);

// Compressing the string data
$zdata = gzdeflate($stringdata );
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than `ob_start()` hackery. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why but this doesn't work on Windows under PHP 5.6.18. "10 is not a valid stream resource"

Comment: Beautiful way. Much better than using ob_*