# PHP View Picture From Base64 String

Tags: php, base64, gd, image

I am connecting to Active-Directory and getting the *thumbnailPhoto* attribute successfully.

I have stored the file in the DB using Base64 encoding which makes the result look like:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RHoRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQEyAAIAAAAUAA ...
```

(Full Base64 encoded string: http://pastebin.com/zn2wDEmd)

Using [a simple Base64 Decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/)  and decoding the string into a binary file and rename that to jpeg and open with an image viewer (here: Irfan View) I get the correct picture - see yourself:

[image: Picture]

How do I achieve this through PHP - I have tried using:

```
<?php 

$data = '/9j/4A...'; //The entire base64 string - gives an error in dreamweaver

$data = base64_decode($data);

$fileTmp = imagecreatefromstring($data);

$newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTmp);

if (!$newImage) {
    echo("<img src=".$newImage."/>");
} 

?>
```

I'm just getting a blank page!

Comment: You worry too much: `echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,', $base64, '">';` - demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JQ8tyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `imagecreatefromstring()` doesn't return a file, but rather an image in memory that should be output with the correct headers.

```
$data = base64_decode($data);

// Create image resource from your data string
$imgdata = imagecreatefromstring($data);

if ($imgdata) {
  // Send JPEG headers
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  // Output the image data
  imagejpeg($imgdata);

  // Clean up the resource
  imagedestroy($imgdata);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: here $imgdata is resource can we apply base64_decode to resouce i want it that way.

Comment: @yourkishore It isn't clear what you are asking. You have `$imgdata` as a GD image resource? You cannot base64 encode that directly - you would need to return the binary string from it to encode.  Post a question with your specific problem.

Comment: Its clarified mate. my question is when imagecopymerge(stuff) will return a resource right ? how do we conver that resource to base64_decode.

Comment: Ah, I think [you want this then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206884/php-gd-how-to-get-imagedata-as-binary-string) use `imagejpeg()` (or whatever format) in conjunction with PHP's output buffering to capture the binary string data, then `base64_encode()` it.  There's nothing there to `base64_decode()` because it hasn't been encoded.