# Getting the binary file contents from a PHP resource

Tags: php, gd

I am currently looking to get the binary file's contents through a resource which is given by the function

```
imagecreatefromstring()
```

I've looked at the documentation on php.net and have been unable to find an answer to my question, the function is

```
resource imagecreatefromstring ( string $image )
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
file_get_contents(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents("file data from a regular file"));
```

This is because I am working on an image class, and it has a 'recreate' functionality, this'll recreate the image and return a new object with the new file's binary content, etc.

Is there any way to get the binary file contents from this resource? Or am I looking at the wrong place

Thanks in advance.

---

Documentation for imagecreatefromstring: [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP GD: How to get imagedata as binary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206884/php-gd-how-to-get-imagedata-as-binary-string)

Comment: Does your server have Imagick installed? Its much more robust and has built ins for things like this too. If its a possibility, you may wish to read into that class object.